# functional javascript regarding to array

Tags: javascript

Below is the question i saw in 65 javascript interview questions,but the answer
 they provided does not seem correct as "Car" is not a function which throw an error when i compile the code:

Given the following array, build me an array of cars with those colours:

```
var colors = ['blue', 'black', 'red'];
var cars = ...;
```

Answer:

```
 var colors = ['blue', 'black', 'red'];
 var cars = colors.map(buildCar);
 function buildCar (color) {
    return new Car(color);
 }
```

Does anybody would explain to me how to modify this answer make it meet the requirement?

Comment: `Car` it's a constructor function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling `new Car(color)`, but you don't have a definition for a `Car`.

Add this:

```
function Car(color)
{
    this.color = color;
}
```

If you want to add more properties, you could do something like:

```
function Car(color, model)
{
    this.color = color;
    this.model = model;
}
var properties = [["blue","Buick"],["red","Benz"],["black","Chevy"]];
var cars = properties.map(buildCar);
// now, the buildCar function will be passed a pair [color,model], because
// each element of the properties array is now an array of length 2
function buildCar(pair)
{
    return new Car(pair[0],pair[1]);
}
```

or, if you don't want to change the `colors` array, you can do

```
function buildCar(color)
{
    var model;
    if (color == "blue")
        model = "Buick";
    else if (color == "red")
        model = "Benz";
    else if (color == "black")
        model = "Chevy";
    return new Car(color,model);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! i am totally new to javascript,do you know if there are some good tutorial online for javascript beginner?

Comment: Thanks!What if i want display different colors corresponding to different car type,for instance i wanna assign blue to Buick,black to Chevy,red to Benz,do you have any idea what should i add to existing bulidCar function?

Comment: sorry i got confused by second one,after you declared properties how do you pass it to function,and what the connection between pair and properties?

Comment: See updated answer. I just like calling an array of length 2 a "pair", and properties is just the name of the array that contains the "pairs"

Comment: i completely got it!Thanks so much,really appreciate it!